# Is there a way to stop execution of calling method to avoid DoubleRenderError in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my controller I have:

```
def update
  case params[:something]
  when 'x'
    if all_is_good
      good_stuff_happens
      flash[:notice] = "Good stuff happened"
    else
      access_denied
    end
  when 'y'
    other_good_stuff_happens
    flash[:notice] = "Other good stuff happened"
  when 'z'
    even_more_good_stuff_happens
    flash[:notice] = "Even more good stuff happened"
  end
  redirect_to good_place_path       
end
```

And in my ApplicationController I have:

```
def access_denied
  redirect_to message_path, :alert => 'Access Denied'
end
```

For the most part, I always want to redirect_to the good_place_path after the case statement.

Occasionally, I want to deny access and leave it at that. Is there a way I can call

```
acccess_denied
```

from my controller and then not return to the calling controller (or else it attempts to do a second redirect and thus I get the DoubleRenderError). I understand I could just put

```
redirect_to good_place_path
```

in each when statement, but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant solution.

Thanks.

Sean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `return` after the `redirect_to` works so adding it after the `access_denied` should work as well. You basically don't want to fall through to the rendering, which is the default.

Comment: Thanks Steve.I tried putting return directly after the redirect_to in the access_denied method, but it still double-rendered because it's now back to the update method and still processing. I then tried your second suggestion and that worked fine. I actually ended up putting: access_denied && return

Comment: Yeah, the `rendering_method and return` is pretty idiomatic in Rails.